# Dynamically create folder when user first time accessing url asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to create folder when user first time accessing url, for this I created this code to create such a folder in my application start file (`global.aspx.cs`). But problem is folder is only created one time, when two users access the url from different ip but  folder is common.

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            const string Chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPOQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            var random = new Random();
            var result = new string(
                Enumerable.Repeat(Chars, 12)
                    .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                    .ToArray());

            var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + result);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            Application["Path"] = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + result);
```

Comment: `application start` runs only one time per application lifetime. `Application_BeginRequest` method runs per each request.

Comment: is there any  way to dynamically change this path variable within application start method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem you are facing because one Application variable will be formed for all users visiting your website,if you want different folders for different user you have to make sessions,because session will be different for different user in `Application_AcquireRequestState` event..

```
 protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        const string Chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPOQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        var random = new Random();
        var result = new string(
            Enumerable.Repeat(Chars, 12)
                .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                .ToArray());

        var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + result);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
       // Application["Path"] = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + result);
        context.Session["Path"] = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + result);
 }
```

Now in your entire application you can access `HttpContext.Session["Path"]` for the current user.

Comment: how i get  path variable in application start method to this session variable

Comment: yes,but how i use   context.Session["Path"]  session in application start method  i try var path=context.Session["Path"].ToString;  but it not work

Comment: @srinathmadusanka...no you don't have to write all this in application start just cut code from const string char line....from application start and then copy my answer put this code block just below application start..

Comment: in my controller    Error 1 The name 'context' does not exist in the current context error come